# How can we effectively compute the sqrt of some element in the group?

Tags: group-theory

I only know one way, if this group is a cyclic group, and we know the element can be expressed in $g^m$, then $g^{(m/2)}$ is the answer.

- Another question, if $m$ is an odd number, can we be sure there is no answer?
- Is it possible to find another generator $g_1$ and an even number $k$ that satisfy the element = $g_1^k$?

If we don't know whether or not the group is cyclic group, the complexity to find the sqrt or to confirm such an answer not exists is as difficult as DLP ?

Comment: This is a pure math question with no effort. If you now $m$ everything easy. Alos, see Rabin Cryptosystem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: Efficient algorithm only exist in specific cases. The problem, in its full generality (finite abelian groups) is equivalent to the integer factorization problem.

> How can we effectively compute the square root of an element in a group?

One case where we can compute a square root is when the group order is known and it is odd. 
Any element $g$ in a group has the following property: if $q$ is the order of the group, then $g^q=1$. This is due to [Lagrage's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)). Equivalently, $g^{q+1}=g$. If $q$ is odd then $\frac{q+1}{2}$ is an integer, hence we can compute $h:= g^{\frac{q+1}{2}}$, which is a square root of $g$.

Another case is the following: Assume $G$ is isomorphic to the direct product group of $k$ copies of the group of order 2 and a group of order odd $q$: 
$$
G \simeq \mathbb{G}_q \times  \prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{Z}_2
$$
where $\mathbb{G}_q$ denotes a group of order $q$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ the group of order 2. Also, importantly, assume **you know how to compute this isomorphism**.

In the group of order 2, the non-unit element is its own inverse, hence it has no square root. This implies the following: Let $g \in G$. Apply the isomorphism to get the representation of $g$ as an element in the direct product above: $g = (g', g_1, ..., g_k)$, where $g' \in \mathbb{G}_q$ and $g_i$ is in the $i$'th $\mathbb{Z}_2$. If there exists $i$ such that $g_i$ is not the unit element, then $g$ does not have a square root.

On the other hand, if $g_i$ is the unit element in all copies of $\mathbb{G}_2$, then the problem reduces to the case of a group of odd order: you just raise $g$ to the power of $\frac{q+1}{2}$.

> Another question, if $m$ is an odd number, can we be sure there is no answer?

No. The above explains this too. Actually, for the above, you don't need to know $m$ (which is typically the case).

> Is it possible to find another generator $g_1$ and an even number $k$ that satisfy the element is equal to $g^k$?

The above addresses this too, since it fully describes the set of squares in the group.

EDIT:

In "Oded Goldreich, Computational complexity: a conceptual perspective" it is shown that finding square roots modulo composite numbers is a computational problem equivalent to integer factorization. Hence, don't expect any "general purpose" algorithm, only algorithm for special cases. One such case is the multiplicative group of invertible element in a field of prime size $p$ - called Tonelli-Shanks.

Comment: Maybe you did it as a simplification, but your decomposition as a product of groups does not always work. Example : $\mathbb Z/2^k\mathbb Z$ is *not* isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^k$.

Comment: @LeoDucas Yes, you're right. Thanks for pointing that out. I edited.

Comment: @Chipotle Thanks! I managed to understand what you mean. It opens a new perspective to me.

Comment: if q is an odd prime number, and g is co-prime with q, and the group is a multiplicative mod p group, then g the power (q-1)/2   also applies?

Comment: @RayJames If we are talking about an abstract group, there is no meaning to g co-prime to q. Perhaps you meant the order of g? and anyway, any number is co-prime to any prime number.

Comment: Yes, sorry I wrote wrong. if we know the order of g, and the order happens to be an odd number, then the order+1 is an even number. Then we can deduce g the power (order+1)/2 is also an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In a generic group, I don't know if it exists really a generic algorithm to solve your problem, but if you group is also a field ($\mathbb{Z}_p$ with $p$ a prime number for example), then you can use the Berlekamp algorithm to factorize $X^2 -x$ where $x$ is your element.

I made an error, I've deleted the wrong part.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to understand Berlekamp algorithm and  discrete logarithms.